# The sum of two projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} (m>n)$ is full rank, and $A_\perp$ span the complementary subspace of $\operatorname{span}(A)$, given the projection matrices $A_1 = A(A^TA)^{-1}A$ and
$A_2=A_{\perp}(A^T_{\perp}A_{\perp})^{-1}A_{\perp}$. Does $A_1 + A_2 = I_{m \times m}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Questions like "this is my problem, solve it for me" are usually badly received here.

Comment: If A and A⊥ has orthonormal basis, $A_1 + A_2 = I_{m \times m} is trivial to prove. The general case is hard to depict. I don't think it's good idea to lecture when someone cannot give any useful help.

Comment: Why do you call $A_1 = A(A^\intercal A)^{-1} A$ a "projection matrix"? I am pretty sure you mean $A_1 = A(A^\intercal A)^{-1}A^\intercal;$ and similarly for $A_2.$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20projection%20matrix,has%20on%20each%20fitted%20value. =>Projection matrix

Comment: Your exercise is quite trivial knowing properties of projectors and you need to edit your question stating what properties you do know and what you can use and what have you tried.

Comment: Then? Sounds like one is knowing everything but not doing anything

Comment: The projector is unique, so if $X$ is any matrix whose columns span a subspace $V$ and $P$ is the orthogonal projector onto $V$ then $P = X(X^\intercal X)^{-1} X^\intercal$ (this assumes $X$ has full rank but it is true even when $X$ does not have full rank if we replace $X^{-1}$ by its pseudoinverse). Additionally, $I-P$ is the orthogonal projector onto the orthocomplement of $V,$ namely $V^\perp = \{x : x \perp V\}.$